# How to use IF and ELSE in function select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, if-statement

This following code will calculate Age based on Gregorian calendar:
I've two lines of sql code that I'm gonna use it into following code using **IF and ELSE**

> This is what I want:

```
      function select($idPatient) 
   {
      if ( $CURRENT_DATE > "1600")
      {
$sql .= "FLOOR((TO_DAYS(GREATEST(IF(decease_date='0000-00-00',CURRENT_DATE,decease_date),IFNULL(decease_date,CURRENT_DATE))) - TO_DAYS(birth_date)) / 365.25) AS age"; 
      }
      else 
      {
$sql .= "FLOOR((TO_DAYS(GREATEST(IF(decease_date='0000-00-00',CURRENT_DATE,decease_date),IFNULL(decease_date,CURRENT_DATE))) - TO_DAYS(birth_date)) / 365.25) - 621 AS age";
      }
      return ($this->exec($sql) ? $this->numRows() : false);
   }
```

> Q: In above code, **IF** is working well but **ELSE** doesn't work

**More information: It's not necessary to use current_date, anything you can use to solve this problem. If we will enter any name it will work too!!!! just because current date is 2015, I used it for sample**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: show your data table schema, sample of data stored and expected result please

Comment: why do you need `decease_date` when you calculate age? to calculate age of person usually you just need his date of birth and current date?

Comment: I updated my question, decease date is for patient age when he died and what was his age!! in clinic history.

Comment: why? what values do you keep for birthdays?

Comment: In our calendar a year is 365.25, yet you put 365 for that case. Should it not be 365.25 in both cases?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I know :-) both of them should be 365.25

Comment: Please have a look again into my updated question, ELSE doesn't work but IF is working well. how to make it work?

Comment: Showing the whole function would be helpful; what kind of value is `$CURRENT_DATE`? What do you mean "doesn't work?" PHP error? SQL error?

Comment: The use of CURRENT_DATE is indeed awkward. In MySql that is synonymous with the CURDATE() function, so I don't see how you will ever get a value before 1600, since it will be the date of today. In the "more information" section you then go on to say that you in fact compare the date of birth with 1600, not the current date. You'll have to straighten that out for us.

Comment: there's no way to change CURRENT_DATE in database to another calendar date. I tried all d ways, those third party library just convert date not changed! anyway, finally I decided to calculate it manually. there's a difference between Gregorian calendar and Persian calendar, this year is 2015, and this yr in persian is 1394, so in IF section, cause 2015 is more than 1600, it works well, but in else when we enter year based on persian calendar doesn't work, and  in opposite way, still it will work well based on persian calendar, but impossible to combine both of them together.

Comment: I updated my question, you can see both of them are working well, but how to use both of them together?? This is my question....

Comment: Since you want to check against a year entered in Persion calendar, you definitely do not want to check current_date (which remains 2015), but the entered date (so date of birth or date of decease if not alive). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to take what you have and smash them both together, into one mysql if then else:

```
IF(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)>1600, 

FLOOR((TO_DAYS(GREATEST(IF(decease_date='0000-00-00',CURRENT_DATE,decease_date),
IFNULL(decease_date,CURRENT_DATE))) - TO_DAYS(birth_date)) / 365),

(FLOOR((TO_DAYS(GREATEST(IF(decease_date='0000-00-00',CURRENT_DATE,decease_date),
IFNULL(decease_date,CURRENT_DATE))) - TO_DAYS(birth_date)) / 365.25) - 621)

) as age
```

So if the condition, the middle sql, else the bottom sql = column age.

Comment: It doesn't work, need to find another method to use if and else inside.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to calculate a persons age, 
by a given date of birth and death. The latter can be 0000-00-00 or NULL, both 
meaning that the person is still alive. Furthermore you want to detect whether the date(s) 
are given by Persian calendar, and correct the calculation accordingly.
Dates are assumed to be according to the Persian calendar when they are before the year 1600.

There seem to be two mistakes in the description:

1. You mention that you want to check CURRENT_DATE with 1600, but that makes no sense because
   CURRENT_DATE is the date of today and will always be greater than 1.1.1600.
   I will assume that was a mistake, and the date of birth was intended.
2. You have 365 in the formula in one case, and 365.25 in another. They both should be 365.25.

Some optimisations of the formula:

The part concerning the date of death can be made shorter:

```
IFNULL(NULLIF(decease_date, '0000-00-00'),CURRENT_DATE)
```

This will treat '0000-00-00' as NULL, and then NULL is replaced by CURRENT_DATE

The original formula calculates the difference in days between decease_date and birth_date, to then
divide the result by 365.25 to get the number of years between them. But to get the number
of years between two days can be done with the function [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestampdiff/), and so you get:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, 
    IFNULL(NULLIF(decease_date, '0000-00-00'), CURRENT_DATE), 
    birth_date) as age
```

Finally, you need to do the Persian calendar detection. Note that if the person deceased
there is in theory no need to do anything different; we may assume birth date and decease date are
given by the same calendar, and so the age will be calculated correctly.
The difference appears when the person has no decease date (i.e. the person is still alive).
In that case you would want to check whether the birth date was before 1600 (Persian 
calendar) and subtract 621 years from the result. 
Now, although that is a way to do it, I suggest another: 
we could use a modulo operation on the total result, which practically comes down to
subtracting 621 for when the age would be higher than that. We use the [modulo operator %](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-mod-function.php) (which is the same as the MOD function):

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, 
    IFNULL(NULLIF(decease_date, '0000-00-00'),
        CURRENT_DATE), 
    birth_date) % 621 as age
```

That's it. No need for another IF.